# How to set a Qt groupbox's icons without using stylesheet?

Tags: qt, icons, qgroupbox

I know there are so many threads explaining about setting the icons of groupbox using stylesheet. But I want to achieve the same using something else other than stylesheet, is it possible?

Background: I was using stylesheets for such modifications in UI, like changing the background color, font, etc.. But our sr. architect says using stylesheets is not a good practice, use QPalette instead. I was able to change groupbox's background and all using qpalette but not getting how to set the icons. Actually I want to set 2 icons for my groupbox, once for checked status and another for unchecked status.

Comment: Use the [`setIcon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#icon-prop) function?

Comment: @thuga, sorry for the confusion, I wanted to ask about groupbox but while typing the question, I mentioned qtoolbutton. So I don't think setIcon would help me here.